# $b|a$ and a|b then $a=b$ help

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on this really simple proof. $b|a$ and a|b then $a=b$, where a,b are positive. I tried to right a=bk and b=am and do something with that but am getting stuck.

Comment: It is not true. For example, take $a=5$ and $b=-5$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a=bk$ and $b=am$, then $a=amk$, what does that tell you about $mk$?

Comment: I guess we need the additional assumption that $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative. Otherwise we could have e.g. $a=1$, $b=-1$.

Comment: My phrasing is amazingly close to yours.

Comment: tells me that mk=1

Comment: Yes, good point Math1000.

Comment: @ajs512 Exactly, so $m$ and $k$ are units(invertible elements) of $\Bbb Z$.  What are the only units in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: i see it now...m=1 and k =1

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

If a = bk
and b = am,
then
a = (am)k = amk.

Divide by a,
and get
1 = mk.

Since m and k are integers,
what does this tell you about them?

Answer (score 1):

$a|b \implies a\le b$ and $b|a \implies b\le a$, so we have $a\le b \le a \implies a=b$.

Comment: Can you show that $(a|b) \implies a \le b$ without using $b = ak$ for some $k$?

Comment: if a|b and a>b, then a/b>1? @martycohen

Comment: But what does it *mean* that a|b?

Comment: that 'a' is a divisor of 'b' @martycohen

Comment: Which means that b/a is an integer, so that b = ak for some integer k.

Comment: @martycohen; i was trying to avoid it, the Q doesn't state that you have to, mind you it needs the stipulate that a,b>0.if b=ka with k (+ve) integer, a/b=1/k -> k=1, takes me back to proving 1>0.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps forward**

1. Substitute one of your expressions into the other
2. Show or use that if $x,y > 1$, then $xy > 1$.
3. Conclude.